# Toilet paper clogging the toilet

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

We have quite an old toilet in our house and every time toilet paper is flushed down it completely clogs, it can be a little or a lot of toilet paper. It doesn't do this with anything else, just toilet paper. We've had to result to getting a bin next to the toilet for now. We had a plumber look quickly at it and he said he couldn't understand it but he's more of a kitchen fitter than anything else.

I have rodded the toilet on numerous occasions, well, everytime someone comes to visit and forgets about the 'no roll down the loo' rule.

Any advice would be very grateful.

Comment: There has to be some amount of paper that will flush, right?  Will one square flush?  Two squares?  Is this a recent problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does this toilet clog so often](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/2196)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the old toilets preformed the best due to not having to comply with water saving laws (at least here in the States). One way manufacturers conformed to the new codes was to (among other things)  narrow the throat of the toilet to increase the water flow to compensate for the decrease in gallons per flush allowed. But it sounds like the paper is getting hung up and caught somewhere near the toilet. Could be an obstruction(kids toy, toothbrush, pencil, etc.) just wedged in the bend at the toilet base or in the sewer drain under the floor. If it can't be plunged, snaked or augured you'll need to remove the toilet to visually check for obstructions. If there is a sink in the same room does the water drain normally? if so the blockage is directly after the toilet (in the sewer line) or inside the toilet.

Comment: Thanks Ojait. 
The bath and sink both drain fine, and so does the toilet with 'human' waste, it's just toilet paper that caues the backlog. I have rodded the drain with a toilet unblocker, with the twisted tooth bit on the end, and that clears it, but it as soon as more toilet paper goes down it clogs again.
I have also had the pipes directly behind and outside out and off to check they're clear and they are. 

Sounds like I'm going to have to take it a part! 

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you might have a thin physical obstruction like a pen or comb in there at the trap in the toilet (like ojait said).  however, prior to pulling the unit, rent an inspection camera and send it through to see if you can spot it.  then, a bent hook on a piece of wire is usually enough to dislodge it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 

I think I'm just going to take it a part and give it all a good clean and check over.